# Problems with using jQuery and variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Please help me, I try to create graphs (in django) using jQuery.

There is example : http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/

But when I try to send the values with variable, jQuery was crashed, please explain me.

There is my code :

```
<script>
var values = "{{ values }}";
var values2 = values.replace(/enter_key/g, '\\n')
values = values2.replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"), values, {
                     legend: 'always',
                     animatedZooms: true,
                     title: 'dygraphs chart template'
                 });          
</script>
```

Values was my string, when I `alert(values)` I see the same format for graph:
http://www.ex.ua/615449293535

Help me! thanks

Comment: Looks like you are missing a comma after `document.getElementById("graph"), values`

Comment: yeah, thanks i try to add comma after and jquery didn't crashed, but graphs don't drawing :(

Comment: @user3731374 Could you share your complete code in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing variable you will need to use text box and use each function and make and array using each function
you may see source code of mumbaisos.com searchlist page it contains its logic